# Best way to display User Profile Dropdown

Tags: user-expectation, ux-designer

We have three ways of displaying Profile Drop-downs as shown below.

Each one of has its strengths and weaknesses.

[image: Profile Drop-down]

Is there any other best way to display the Profile Drop-down?

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 is good practice, as the user is aware (in most of the cases) of his "User Name" so he will not  be interested in his user name all the time upfront (in level one). It's ok if you are hiding it in level two (Behind a click). 
For example, twitter uses the same technique to get rid of similar issues, that you are facing.

There are few other ways too, you can restrict the username size or you can just show first name or last name or you can truncate the user name after certain (10 or 12) characters etc.

Comment: I guess (in most of the cases) the user is also aware of how his own face looks like ;)

Comment: It's about showing a action point, to start other activities.

Answer (score 1):

Option **1** and **3** are both viable options depending on what type of service you are offering. Regarding option 3 you can look at the answer given by **bagaria**.

There are, however, numerous cases where displaying more information about the user than just than just their profile image is preferable. One case that comes to mind are services where the user can administer more that one account or plan. Having that information available to the user at all times removes the stress of having to click their profile image in order to see that they are editing information for the right account/plan.

When displaying more information next to the image, like a user name, I always go for **Option 1** since is gives more consistency to the UI (at least if you choose to display this information in the top right corner). This option will always keep the image in the top right corner where as Option 2 will result in the image having random placements depending on how long the user name is.

Here is an illustration:

[image: Option 1 vs. Option 2]

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change your UI due to technical problems (overlap, image move). I suggest to not let these issues affect your UI decision. Just choose what is right for you and make it work.

Personally I think Option #2 is preferred.